# What is the difference between file modification time and file changed time?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I am confused between the term file modification time and file changed time. Can anyone help to make it clearer?

Comment: What we need is a list of system calls that change each :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

mtime is modification time - contents have changed.

ctime is status change time - perms and ownership as well as contents.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) says:

> ```
> * mtime: time of last modification (ls -l),
> * ctime: time of last status change (ls -lc) and
> * atime: time of last access (ls -lu).
> ```
>
> Note that ctime is not the time of
> file creation. Writing to a file
> changes its mtime, ctime, and atime. A
> change in file permissions or file
> ownership changes its ctime and atime.
> Reading a file changes its atime. File
> systems mounted with the noatime
> option do not update the atime on
> reads, and the relatime option
> provides for updates only if the
> previous atime is older than the mtime
> or ctime. Unlike atime and mtime,
> ctime cannot be set with utime() (as
> used e.g. by touch); the only way to
> set it to an arbitrary value is by
> changing the system clock.

Comment: Note there is also a hirarchy:
- modification: mtime, ctime, and atime are changed.
- status change: ctime and atime are changed.
- access: only atime is changed.

Comment: The edit queue's full, but if anyone reading this has enough rep, the most up-to-date version of the URL in this post is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call), and it's worth editing in just to get the https version of the URL.