# Difference in file time

Tags: timestamp, qnx, difference

I am writing a script to find the difference between file creation/modification times using a bash script.  Running QNX I cannot use any common themed date functions that would make this easy.  I am currently approaching this modifying the date from the ls command:

```
    last=0
    current=0
#ls -l /path/*.log | awk '{print $8}' | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc |
ls -l /path/*.log | awk '{print $8}' |
while read fname 
do
    current=$(fname | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc)
    echo $current
    echo $fname
    if [ $last -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "the difference is $($current - $last) minutes"
        last=$current    
    else
        last=$current
        echo $fname
    fi      
done
```

the first commented ls produces what I need, the time in seconds, the while statement doesnot work though, not being able to find an integer based file.  If I use the second ls command the sed will not modify the hh:mm based date and the difference won't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few points to your query:**
1. File creation timestamp is not stored in linux. Only *accessed time*, *modified time*, and *changed time* are stored for any file. [refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79824/2331887 for the differences between them.]
2. Now, reconsider and decide which timestamp difference you need to find. One would be the latest *modified time* would be best to use for calculation based on fact *whenever the content gets modified*, and the other time for the difference would be ? [are you looking for difference between previous modified time and latest modified time]

**Few points to your code:**
1. 8th parameter of *long listing* file description would output 
a) *hh:mm* for the files that are modified in current year and 
b) *yyyy* instead of *hh:mm* for the files that were modified in previous years.
Hence, ambiguity would occur in your calculation.
**Solution** : You can use `ls --time-style='+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M' -l *.log | awk '{print $7}'` for the case you want calculation based on *hh*60+mm* . This calculation further is not taking care of different dates.
 Instead, for calculating time difference, I would recommend to use `stat -c %Y *.log` [ which provides last modified time (*in seconds*) since Epoch *(midnight 1/1/1970)* ] 

2. The bug in your code is very small. Change `current=$(fname | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc);` with `current=$(echo $fname | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc);`
Please note, this would provide correct output, only and only if modified dates for the file are same.